# Sending text input into another application with Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'd like to create a small Android app, which would send the current date and time into another android application's (OneNote) input control. I cannot modify the receiving application.

In my mind the best way to do this would be to add a new button to the system keyboard (GBoard), but that looks like impossible to do.

On the other hand creating a new custom keyboard only for that seems overkill.
What's a good way to do this? In particular how do I do this with Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look **Broadcast Receivers** in Xamarin.Android, Broadcast receiver is used for sending a message to same application or another application.

Here is the short tutorial [Broadcast Receivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers)